# Cannot create readthedocs from enterprise git repository

Tags: git, webhooks, read-the-docs

I am trying to create a RTD page from a GitHub Enterprise repository. It is public and you can view it [here](https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik/grouppagetest). However, I am getting an error while importing my repository in RTD:

**This repository doesn't have a valid webhook set up. That means it won't be rebuilt on commits to the repository. 
You can resync your webhook to fix this**

I am using the `import manually` option to import this repository because I am unable to connect my enterprise github account to the readthedocs account.

I have added the `readthedocs service` for this repo as shown below:

[image]

I am also getting some json data under Recent Deliveries with the warning `Invalid HTTP Response 400`:

**Request**:

Headers:

```
Request URL: https://readthedocs.org/github
Request method: POST
content-type: application/json
Expect: 
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/e8f3622
X-GitHub-Delivery: 699ff500-15ea-11e6-83f2-b369b6587fb1
X-GitHub-Event: ping
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=8df58dc58f48bbd90fd5542d0d15a22fac0cae6a
```

Payload:

```
{
  "zen": "Anything added dilutes everything else.",
  "hook_id": 44,
  "hook": {
    "url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/hooks/44",
    "test_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/hooks/44/test",
    "ping_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/hooks/44/pings",
    "id": 44,
    "name": "web",
    "active": true,
    "events": [
      "push"
    ],
    "config": {
      "url": "https://readthedocs.org/github",
      "content_type": "json",
      "insecure_ssl": "0",
      "secret": "********"
    },
    "last_response": {
      "code": null,
      "status": "unused",
      "message": null
    },
    "updated_at": "2016-05-09T13:32:02Z",
    "created_at": "2016-05-09T13:32:02Z"
  },
  "repository": {
    "id": 1150,
    "name": "grouppagetest",
    "full_name": "rathik/grouppagetest",
    "owner": {
      "login": "rathik",
      "id": 177,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/avatars/u/177?",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik",
      "html_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik",
      "followers_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/followers",
      "following_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/repos",
      "events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "ldap_dn": "CN=RATHIK,OU=Secured,OU=Corporate Users,DC=chop,DC=edu"
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik/grouppagetest",
    "description": "Template for group page",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest",
    "forks_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/repos/rathik/grouppagetest/releases{/id}",
    "created_at": "2016-05-05T15:37:49Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-05T15:37:49Z",
    "pushed_at": "2016-05-06T19:14:37Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.research.chop.edu/rathik/grouppagetest.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.research.chop.edu:rathik/grouppagetest.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik/grouppagetest.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik/grouppagetest",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 0,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": null,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  },
  "sender": {
    "login": "rathik",
    "id": 177,
    "avatar_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/avatars/u/177?",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik",
    "html_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/rathik",
    "followers_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/followers",
    "following_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/repos",
    "events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://github.research.chop.edu/api/v3/users/rathik/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "ldap_dn": "CN=RATHIK,OU=Secured,OU=Corporate Users,DC=chop,DC=edu"
  }
}
```

**Response 400:**

Headers:

```
Connection: close
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 09 May 2016 13:32:07 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: sessionid=vgsi1p5ju1r6p3czbl36rub5o3diybdx; Domain=readthedocs.org; expires=Mon, 23-May-2016 13:32:06 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
```

Body:

```
ref argument required to build branches.
```

Comment: Did you set up a web hook? See: http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks.html

Generally, I know from experience that using RtD with a public GitHub Enterprise repo can work.

Comment: I did setup a webhook and still not able to create it. I tried the same thing with my other github profile and it works. I can't see any errors except the webhook part.